# How to add multiple subviews on view without hiding the last added subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, subview

This is my code

```
  var button = [UIButton?](count:3, repeatedValue: UIButton())
  for i in 0...2{

            button[i]!.tag = i
            button[i]!.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) *(collectionViewLove?.frame.width)!/3,0,(collectionViewLove?.frame.width)!/3, 30)
            button[i]!.setTitle(titleForButtonsOneSelected[i], forState: .Normal)
            button[i]!.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            button[i]!.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            button[i]!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            button[i]!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            button[i]!.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            view.addSubview(button[i]!)

        }
```

The problem is only the last button added to the view is getting shown. How do I show all the button objects in the view?

EDIT:
The frame values for UIButton I am getting

> (0.0, 0.0, 106.666666666667, 30.0)
>
> (106.666666666667, 0.0, 106.666666666667, 30.0)
>
> (213.333333333333, 0.0, 106.666666666667, 30.0)

Comment: change the button frame every time...specially x and y

Comment: I am changing it  in the code above.

Comment: How are your buttons created?

Comment: As you can see, the button frames are different in the EDIT.

Comment: @Eendje var button = [UIButton?](count:3, repeatedValue: UIButton())

Comment: If you create your buttons like that, they will all be the same, e.g. changing the first one will also change the second and the third. Basically you have just one button.

Comment: So I create separate buttons then right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let buttons = Array(0...2).map { number -> UIButton in
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(number) * collectionViewLove!.frame.width / 3, 0, collectionViewLove!.frame.width / 3, 30))

    button.tag = number
    button.setTitle(titleForButtonsOneSelected[number], forState: .Normal)
    buttontitleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    view.addSubview(button)

    return button
}
```

This way you have 3 different buttons in `buttons`. You can also customize the buttons right there as well.

Edit:

```
let buttons = Array(0...2).forEach {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat($0) * collectionViewLove!.frame.width / 3, 0, collectionViewLove!.frame.width / 3, 30))

    button.tag = $0
    button.setTitle(titleForButtonsOneSelected[$0], forState: .Normal)
    buttontitleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: Basically there was a single button object for the button array. I get it.

Comment: Right. I can update the answer with how you can customize the button inside if you want.

Comment: If you don't need to access the buttons later, you can also use `for-in` or `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `button[i]!.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) *(collectionViewLove?.frame.width)!/3,0,(collectionViewLove?.frame.width)!/3, 30)` is producing the same frame each time, so your buttons will be superimposed on each other. You need to have something dynamic in your call to have them be in different spots and visible.

Comment: That isn't the issue. I printed the x and y and they are changing dynamically.

Comment: Ok, then make sure that like @Eendje said, you are actually creating separate buttons. One issue could be that you've put the same button in the array 3 times so it's just being moved to its final spot.